# Joomla/PHP: How to inject the content (body) of an other article into an article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

Dear Joomla Community,

I'm working on a little Joomla (3.4.1) system plugin that injects some meta tags into an article. It's working fine so far. Now I'd like to extend the plugin to copy the content of an other article into the article that's processed by the plugin. Is this somehow possible?

To be more precise, what I'm looking for is:

- How can I get the content/body from an other article from inside my plugin?
- How can the content/body then be injected into the current article (i.e. the article the plugin is currently processing)?
- Currently the plugin does all it's work in onBeforeRender(). Is that the right place to read and inject an other article?

Any advice is welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load/print any article by *articleId* using this code:

```
<?php
    $articleId = 22; // Your article id here
    $table_plan         =  JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
    $table_plan_return  = $table_plan->load(array('id'=>$articleId));
    echo $table_plan->introtext;
?>
```

You can also output the full text using `echo $table_plan->fulltext;` if your articles contain a Read More separation. However, keep in mind that `fulltext` is empty if no Read More separator has been added to the text.

---

**Update:**

In order to *replace* any article with the given content, you can use `onContentPrepare`:

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        if ($context == "com_content.article") { // run only in article views
            $articleId = 22; // Your article id here
            $table_plan         =  JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
            $table_plan_return  = $table_plan->load(array('id'=>$articleId));
            $row->text = $table_plan->introtext;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the parameters ($context, $row, $params, $page = 0) and `if/else`-statements to control when and how the articles will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot! One question though: Putting the code into onContentPrepare() causes the echo statement to print the content of the injected article above the destination articles headline/title. Is there a way to completely replace the content of the destination article?

Comment: @user324820, please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer - especially for including the `if ($context == "com_content.article")` part, I would have missed that. Totally awesome!